# CSS entire menu item clickable

Tags: button, clickable

I have a unordered list for my navigation menu but only the text is clickable when I would like the entire 'button' clickable. How do I do this?

HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li class="current_link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="early.html">Growing Up and School</a></li>
        <li><a href="career.html">Films</a></li>
        <li><a href="jamesbond.html">James Bond</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Pictures</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it: http://jsfiddle.net/Ymkpb/

```
<ul class="clickables">
    <li>item one <a href="http://www.google.com">link one</a></li>
    <li>item two <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">link two</a></li>
    <li>item three <a href="http://www.msn.com">link three</a></li>
    <li>item four <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">link four</a></li>
</ul>


$$('.clickables').each(function(clickable) {
    var list = clickable.getElements('li');

    list.addEvent('click', function() {
        var link = this.getElement('a');
        if(this.getFirst('a')) {
            window.location = link
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about CSS menu, I think you have a CSS.
Add following code to your CSS file.
To make the anchor fill the entire menu item.

```
ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```